# Background process running in foreground after upgrade to 3.8.7

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Upgraded from `3.7.6` to `3.8.7`.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def back_sleep(): sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=back_sleep, daemon=True)
    proc.start()
```

Error I can't seem to get around. Other solutions point to pool. Tried setting `Pool()` too.

```
...spawn.py", line 126, in _main self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'back_sleep' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I want my shell/ kernel to be immediately available to the user while the background proc (cpu intensive task) runs for a while.

Comment: `target=back_sleep(sec=sec)` is an *immediate call* of the function, running in the main process.  You then launch another process to run its return value, which is None.  You need to pass *the function itself* to `Process()`.

Comment: thank you. When i do so `proc = Process(target=back_sleep, daemon=True)` and call `proc.start()` I get `spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'back_sleep' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: You need to pay closer attention to the requirements in the `multiprocessing` documentation - everything other than definitions of functions needs to be inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried the if statement. same error. also, that if statement just evaluates to True? no magic?

Comment: You've also made the process a daemon, which exits when no other non-daemon processes exist, and the main process immediately exits.

Answer (score 1):

In a separate file (back_sleep.py):

```
from time import sleep

def back_sleep(sec: int):
    sleep(sec)
    print('hey')

sec = 2
back_sleep(sec)
```

And in another file (main.py):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([
                "python3",
                "back_sleep.py",
            ])
```

Then run the main.py file.

Comment: Did you test the above?

Comment: I did. It runs. Upvoted. Figuring out how to return output.

Comment: Looks like putting the target function of Process in a separate.py works too. alternative to subprocess

Comment: Generally for your purpose to have the shell available immediately. The best method is subprocess.

Comment: Why not just a shell command (Windows): `start /b python -c "import time; time.sleep(5)"`

Comment: @MarkTolonen It’s a pip package that has a method that runs a background process for users that are primarily in jupyter/ rstudio

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Jupyter is important info that should be part of the question. When using multiprocessing, in Jupyter the worker function has to be in a separate python file and imported to work properly.

Comment: No. Th pip package is being called from jupyter. I figured it now. I made the target function top level and now the pickle attribute error is gone for some reason, but that doesn’t explain why sleep doesnt work.